# Почему при нажатии на кнопку бот пишет ,что ошибка взаимодействия?

Tags: python, discord.py

я пишу код для бота для дизайна и у меня возникла ошибка при проверки бота. Бот отправляет сообщение "Ошибка взаимодействия" . Подскажите пожалуйста ,что я делаю не так?
Примечание: бот должен отправлять сообщение в лс.

вот код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@commands.command(aliases = ['товары'])
async def products(self, ctx):

    two = Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label="Шапка", id="embed1")
    three = Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label="Аватарка", id="embed2")
    four = Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label="КомплектYT", id="embed3")



    embed1 = discord.Embed(title="Шапка", description=f'**Стоимость:** <:qiwi:909495282444697630> **киви - 80, голда - 40**', colour=discord.Colour.greyple())
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Аватарка", description=f'**Стоимость:** <:qiwi:909495282444697630> **киви - 50, голда - 25**', colour=discord.Colour.greyple())
    embed3 = discord.Embed(title="КоплектYT", description=f'**Стоимость:** <:qiwi:909495282444697630> **киви - 100, голда - 50**', colour=discord.Colour.greyple())

    e2 = discord.Embed(
            title=f'Выбери что ты хочешь заказать!',
            description=f'Привет! Я `JARVIS`,выбери ,что ты хочешь заказать!После того как просмотришь и выбиришь товар отправь в чат команду `$buy <товар> <коментарий>`',
            color=good_color
        )

    await ctx.author.send(
        embed=e2,
        components=[                    # attach the buttons
            [two,
            three,
    four]
        ]       
    )

            
    buttons = {
            "embed1": embed1,       
            "embed2": embed2,
            "embed3": embed3,
    }

    while True:             # this is important if you want that people can klick the buttons multiple times.
        event = await self.client.wait_for("button_click")          
        if event.channel is not ctx.channel:                # wait for the button click, get the button id
            return
        if event.channel == ctx.channel:
            response = buttons.get(event.component.id)     
            if response is None:
                await event.channel.send(
                    "Что-то пошло не так. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз."            # error
                )
            if event.channel == ctx.channel:
                await event.respond(    
                    type=4,      # send the message (7 is editing the message)
                    embed=response
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в ответ на нажатие кнопки `await response.edit_origin()`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Возможно вы забыли обернуть самого бота

   DiscordComponents(self.bot) # Для когов

   DiscordComponents(bot) # Без когов
2. Если вы пишите эту команду в гильдии, то контекст (ctx) будет указывать на канал в гильдии, а event.channel на канал переписки из-за этого будет не проходить условие.